# Contract Law: Sale by Auction; Undeclared Reserve Price

Tags: contract-law

What is the correct position: during an auction, the Auctioneer accepted a bid but when the client returned to pick up the sold item, the Auctioneer declined to get the money saying the accepted price was fall below the reserve price. Can the bidder who won sue for breach of contract?

NB: The Auctioneer did not mention that there was a reserve price on the item.

Comment: The laws in place that cover auctions vary widely between locations.  It might help if you noted the country and state where you are.

Comment: @jwh20 "*The laws in place that cover auctions vary widely between locations.*" Could you provide two or more statutes with discrepancies that are relevant to the OP's inquiry? As far as the bidder is concerned this is a simple contract. It seems that he has a viable claim of breach of contract.

Comment: @IñakiViggers How about the marriage-auction scheme Herodotus describes for Babylon? That followed **extremely** different rules than modern auctions.

Comment: @IñakiViggers No.

Comment: @Trish "*How about the marriage-auction scheme Herodotus describes for Babylon?*" That reference is too vague, outdated at best, and completely irrelevant to the OP's inquiry.

Comment: What was the form of the auctioneer “accepting” the bid?  Did they smack the gavel and declare “sold”?  This info would seem to be key as to whether or not a contract was formed.

Comment: Which way is the client wanting to go in this case? Is the client desiring the item, but only at the auction price, or is the client being told the item is theirs and they must now pay the reserve price?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the bids are the offer which the auctioneer may, but is not bound to, accept. (*Chitty on Contracts*, § 4-025). Many Sale of Goods Acts specify that the "**sale is complete when the auctioneer announces its completion by the fall of a hammer**" (see [Ontario's Sale of Goods Act](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90s01#BK60); see also *Chitty on Contracts*, § 4-025). If the auctioneer is not going to accept the bid, the auctioneer may withdraw the lot.

If the property is put up for auction *subject to a reserve price*, no contract is formed if the auctioneer mistakingly purports to accept a bid lower than the reserve price (*Chitty on Contract*, § 4-026). As for how this should play out in practice, see [*Halifax, City of v. Miller and Johnson Auctioneers Ltd.*, 40 N.S.R. (2d) 35](https://www.canlii.org/en/ns/nsca/doc/1980/1980canlii4467/1980canlii4467.html): "the proper course for the auctioneer... was to make known that there were reserve prices at the auction and if in the case... the reserve price was not reached to withdraw the unit from the auction," citing Halsbury's Laws of England (4th Ed.), vol. 2, para. 747, at p. 383.

Any after-the-fact declaration of the existence of a reserve bid has no bearing on the formation of the contract.

**The only thing that matters is whether the property *is put to auction* subject to a reserve price**.

- If it *is not put up subject to a reserve price*, then the contract for sale is formed with the highest bidder when the auctioneer announces the completion of the auction.
- If the property *is put up subject to a reserve price*, then no contract is formed, even where there is purported acceptance by the auctioneer.